# How to draw lineplot with matplotlib that changes the color?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

I calculate a histogram for the hue value of an image (hsv) and draw the histogram with `plt.plot(histh)`.

However, what I want to do now is to let the line change its colour in correspondence with the hue value it is representing.

I tried this:

```
color=iter(cm.hsv(np.linspace(0,1,180)))
for x, y in enumerate(histh, start=1):
    c=next(color)
    plt.plot(x, y, '.', color=c, ms=10)
```

Obviously, I do not get a line but a scatter plot. However, using '-' for the marker to get a solid line results into an empty plot.

So, how can I get this color changing line which uses the hue color range in a lineplot?

Comment: Look at this example http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/multicolored_line.html

Comment: Thx, it is true I haven't found this example. However,  the description of what is happening in it and its logic is completely absent which makes it a bit hard to understand and to modify for you own needs.